# how to resolve this error File "test.py", line 5, in <module> for _ in range(b[0]): TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Covid-19 is spreading fast! There are `N` cities, numbered from `0` to
> `N−1`, arranged in a circular manner. City `0` is connected to city
> `1`, `1` to `2`, …, and city `N−1` to city `0`.
>
> The virus is currently at city `X`. Each day, it jumps from its
> current city, to the city `K` to its right, i.e., from city `X` to the
> city `(X+K)%N`. As the virus jumps, the cities in between don't get
> infected. Cities once infected stay infected. You live in city `Y`.
> Find if it will reach your city eventually. If it will, print YES,
> else print NO.
>
> The first line of the input consists of an integer `T`, the number of
> test cases.
>
> The first and only line of each test case contains four
> space-separated integers - `N`, `K`, `X` and `Y`, denoting the number
> of cities, the size of jumps, Covid's current city, and the city that
> you live in, respectively.

This is the code I tried for it:

```
print("1- first write the number of times the program should run \n 2- write the of number of cities \n 3- size of jumps \n 4- virus current city \n 5- city you live in")

for _ in range(int(input())):
    a=[int(x) for x in input(). split()]
    for b in a:
        for _ in range(b[0]):
            b[2]=(b[2]+b[1])%b[0]
            if b[2]==b[3]:
                print("yes")
            else:
                print("NO")
```

Now I write this code as the first line will tell me how many times the code will run. Second line helps me to get the four values which will be different as to how many times the code will run that is `a[0],a[1]..a[3]`. and the third line will ittrate the first values of `a` into `b`.

But I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "covid.py", line 6, in <module>
    for _ in range(b[0]):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

---

Example input:

```
2
6 2 5 3
12 3 4 2
```

Expected output:

```
YES
NO
```

Comment: When posting questions about specific errors, please try to give a short explanation on what your code is actually doing (so we get some context) and the full error inside the question (Everything from `Traceback most recent...` to the end)

Comment: Covid-19 is spreading fast! There are N cities, numbered from 0 to (N−1), arranged in a circular manner. City 0 is connected to city 1, 1 to 2, …, city (N−2) to city (N−1), and city (N−1) to city 0

.

The virus is currently at city X
. Each day, it jumps from its current city, to the city K to its right, i.e., from city X to the city (X+K)%N. As the virus jumps, the cities in between don't get infected. Cities once infected stay infected. You live in city Y. Find if it will reach your city eventually. If it will, print YES, else print NO.

Comment: Please don't use comments to give additional information. [edit] your question with the information needed...

Comment: And to answer your question - you don't need `b`... Simply remove the `for b in a` and replace `b` with `a` inside the loop. You simply want to do `a[2] = (a[2]+a[1])%a[0]` etc.

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) It will help you write better questions

Comment: @SafeerKhan, can you please provide us with some sample data that you intend to process through your program. My understanding is that your source data may have numbers and strings. Also, i am not sure how we will use b[0]. Example data will be helpful

Comment: @SafeerKhan Please don't change the question with an edit!

Answer (score 1):

Code is hard to read but i'll try my best to solve this:
a is an integer, and integers  can't be subscripted(basically accessed like an array eg. `list[0], string[0:len(string)], tupl[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have `a` defined as a list with values of integers. You are iterating through the list and trying to subscript the integer.

Let's take an example of the items you may enter as inputs:
10, 20, 30, ABCD, XYZ

You are expecting the below line of code to split the data into multiple elements. As you can see from the input, you have integers and strings. Your code will fail when it tries to process the list comprehension for `a`

```
a=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Let's assume you entered all numeric values and also integers, say:

```
10 20 30 40 50
```

Now `a` will have [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

Look at the next few lines of code:

```
for b in a:
    for _ in range(b[0]):
        b[2]=(b[2]+b[1])%b[0]
        if b[2]==b[3]:
```

What do you think is happening here? For the first iteration, b will have a value of 10. It is not a string and not a list. So the next line `for _ in range(b[0]):` will fail. Similarly, any reference of `b[i]` where `i` is an index of `b` will fail.

I have marked the lines that may be in error. Please review them.

```
a=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
for b in a:
    for _ in range(b[0]): #are you sure b is a list? this will fail
        b[2]=(b[2]+b[1])%b[0]. #you cannot do this as b is not a list
        if b[2]==b[3]: #same here, this will fail
            print("yes")
        else:
            print("NO")
```

Instead you can just use `a` and do everything you are trying to do within the loop `for b in a:` Instead of the entire section of the for loop, just add a line

```
b = (a[2]+a[1]) % a[0]

if b == a[3]:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: with the updated input values shared by OP, I still think the code `b = (a[2]+a[1]) % a[0]` will work.

Comment: It will work, but this simulates a single jump. It doesn't tell you if it will reach `y` in the end or not...